# Not able to login to WSO2 Api Manager's Publisher/ Devportal WUI in WSO2 Identity Server using SAML2

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

While being new to the WSO2 stack, we are dealing with a few challenges.
One is to achieve a successful login to the Publisher/ Devportal via the Identity Server.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-25 12:55:18,675] [43127480-b582-4ee6-9639-fbca19bc3583]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.validators.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestValidator} - Signature validation for Authentication Request failed for the request of Issuer :apim in tenantDomain:carbon.super
```

We have enabled the debug mode on Identity Server side and the logs look like this:

```
    TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-25 11:16:10,951] [] DEBUG {org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol} - Found processor [null] for socket [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@18630c7f:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/ip_of_IS:9443 remote=/5.2.192.217:53221]]
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-25 11:43:11,381] [] DEBUG {org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol} - Processing socket [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@18630c7f:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/ip_of_IS:9443 remote=/5.2.192.217:60128]] with status [OPEN_READ]
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-25 11:43:11,382] [] DEBUG {org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol} - Found processor [null] for socket [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@18630c7f:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/ip_of_IS:9443 remote=/5.2.192.217:60128]]
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-25 11:43:11,382] [] DEBUG {org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol} - Popped processor [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor@1fa8141e] from cache
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-25 11:43:11,384] [] DEBUG {org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer} - Received [GET /samlsso?SAMLRequest=lZJdT8IwFIbv%2FRVL74GtjK%2BGzRAMCQkmBMELb0zpzrRxbWdPh%2Fx8uwG6CzR6257z9jnP6fT2qIrgABal0QmJuiEJQAuTSf2SkN120RmT2%2FRmilwVJZtV7lVv4L0CdMEMEazzbXOjsVJgH8AepIDdZpWQV%2BdKZL0eL2WXxntr3sB2jS6kBjaJ435PGKWM5j6QBHc%2BTmruGoSvTn91vbVmQTQkWBgroGFKSM4LBBIs7xLyvN8LMYonYc5Hg35GR8PxPg%2BHAnKa5XmYRb4M1xxRHuC7EbGCpUbHtUsIDSnthLRDB9twwuI%2Bi6IunYRPJHi8qKK1Ki9PI2vkJKSymhmOEpnmCpA5wR5m9yvmK1lpjTPCFCQ9q2zes38P4BfbJPVO1bTXjjmF0pKddwNZY8UvxsHRBXOjSm4l1thKaqkq1Uan%2F2OnrB0%2BLzzZBvJ23p8n%2BbVMMFFn%2B%2BN6Vx%2FGZmsPAsJPt7VcY2msO2m4TpSeL3%2Bwkl4Utj91%2Bgk%3D&RelayState=ab00c57f-fe47-46b8-8840-7ffb891428ce&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2F04%2Fxmldsig-more%23rsa-sha256&Signature=UuHBW3DPs6pz7s7uyd2xIAYNmjihvHIHxQvnnAKEo%2FTzsk47Rw%2BtTPWAtg0vDftwjIjrn8sGW6ZRHOJPZLGLnILIkCY0rnOxLsRGxzmAYR6WAp9RvSmi31XT6I6gyiqC6I%2Bq3FAgFyczVWP0JGtlDooqyvTpZltIpHRtiuShGsUz5FCagD3HJt49gm6zgc7CoMXa21IAu1g6HnLNFYGVDaBNG8B0DAVHKcC1Dxzs%2ByozUQaNBgabZoHpi2P4Lf0sBm2uRrKPnzpAc4gmZapGmlq%2FnqoQUKOkeAN2LlkxMIUEhRywqYLTcLHfTWgQhnDBGptcNBMTX5kZQDEbKftvAA%3D%3D HTTP/1.1
Host: wso2is_hostname:9443
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Referer: https://apim_hostname:9443/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: MSG16455177742430.7191048087063175=true; MSG16455177954750.2595548140579492=true; MSG16455178136750.09520752137458788=true; MSG16455178688400.6735273130969622=true; MSG16455178741310.10609477531366851=true; MSG16455179326060.3028886753637441=true; MSG16455179425120.923544406893808=true; MSG16455180639860.3453874502095743=true; MSG16455180746090.5577178784575753=true; MSG16455232438850.07947811451010722=true; wso2.carbon.rememberme=admin-c3e45ca6-ff7e-47a4-a956-b150c5015db0; menuPanel=visible; menuPanelType=main; sessionNonceCookie-869da04d-4619-4534-8bb1-acedcce3c8f4=026d0ec4-90c0-4fe1-86f5-d0d9650213d1; MSG16456202843170.5426942841607011=true; MSG16456207463390.965656332968078=true; MSG16456215190930.760197284371141=true; current-breadcrumb=; JSESSIONID=B8BF12B8A89C9AAD94884A79238ACCB6; requestedURI=../../carbon/application/load-service-provider.jsp?spName=apim_hostname; MSG16456258298740.9126911241141477=true; MSG16456258884800.25972541799729765=true; sessionNonceCookie-a1695150-f34e-4d72-a537-1caa8d8ea231=2fba0f43-2cdf-4fe5-88ea-dbfc835e24fe

]
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-02-25 11:43:11,542] [ab00c57f-fe47-46b8-8840-7ffb891428ce]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.validators.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestValidator} - Signature validation for Authentication Request failed for the request of Issuer :apim in tenantDomain:carbon.super
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-25 11:43:11,552] [] DEBUG {org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor} - Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@254c4286:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@18630c7f:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/ip_of_IS:9443 remote=/5.2.192.217:60128]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-25 11:43:11,553] [] DEBUG {org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol} - Pushed Processor [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor@1fa8141e]
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-25 11:43:11,559] [] DEBUG {org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol} - Processing socket [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@18630c7f:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/ip_of_IS:9443 remote=/5.2.192.217:60128]] with status [OPEN_READ]
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-25 11:43:11,560] [] DEBUG {org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol} - Found processor [null] for socket [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@18630c7f:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/ip_of_IS:9443 remote=/5.2.192.217:60128]]
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-25 11:43:11,560] [] DEBUG {org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol} - Popped processor [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor@1fa8141e] from cache
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-25 11:43:11,562] [] DEBUG {org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer} - Received [GET /authenticationendpoint/samlsso_notification.do?status=Error+when+processing+the+authentication+request%21&statusMsg=Please+try+login+again.&SAMLResponse=fVJLb9swDL73Vwi6xw%2FFSRMhdlE0KFBgvTRtD7sMjE0nQm3KE%2BVi%2B%2FeVnQTdfMhFAKmP4vfQ5u5P24hPdGws5TKNEimQSlsZOuTy7fVxtpJ3xc2GoW1Up1%2BQO0uMYovsDYEfp47ed6zjGDoTqWzv7Ae6yFJjCPU6y%2BZxadvWEvT%2BKMXTNpe%2FstssXSdzDAeualUvV%2Fvlfg5pucZyuawXAcbc4xOxB%2FK5VIlSs0TN1OI1WetsrtM0WmSLn1K8X6irgXoQQ6xPZHPZO9IW2LAmaJG1L%2FXu%2FvmHDlDdOettaRtZnLTpcaETj9a14K%2FPDh1TzeoRqpG88X%2F%2F2319HJjRDc7JYrBkatkm%2FpdQcbF%2B58H3PCkfbIXiHZoer6%2FkER3i%2B92H4NDJePLQMzLDAYudOYRUe4fiExpTjQGLIFTcB6aD0vLUOr8kajANViMi3At3bttanP3U4VO0wpDwSCHKrW3BkC7B7S1F3HfoznqnTCbt7%2FryB4sv&RelayState=ab00c57f-fe47-46b8-8840-7ffb891428ce&sp=apim&tenantDomain=carbon.super HTTP/1.1
Host: wso2is_hostname:9443
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Referer: https://apim_hostname:9443/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=5D91FD4BB686928E93AD7A954099653A390FBC1F5F42E2533D10F993E800A9F4B2D6DE2D0D17F33E2D68D3068F22F02E18C40D32DBD00A63990A7722A0C66FC8648AF321C2138EC10E420760F797E48C8765AD7C543B4460778ADC59C80D78A5AE8472D65A66721F93D4B902EF7A1BB4F83679413F0D41D29161160C0E326DC1; MSG16455177742430.7191048087063175=true; MSG16455177954750.2595548140579492=true; MSG16455178136750.09520752137458788=true; MSG16455178688400.6735273130969622=true; MSG16455178741310.10609477531366851=true; MSG16455179326060.3028886753637441=true; MSG16455179425120.923544406893808=true; MSG16455180639860.3453874502095743=true; MSG16455180746090.5577178784575753=true; MSG16455232438850.07947811451010722=true; wso2.carbon.rememberme=admin-c3e45ca6-ff7e-47a4-a956-b150c5015db0; menuPanel=visible; menuPanelType=main; sessionNonceCookie-869da04d-4619-4534-8bb1-acedcce3c8f4=026d0ec4-90c0-4fe1-86f5-d0d9650213d1; MSG16456202843170.5426942841607011=true; MSG16456207463390.965656332968078=true; MSG16456215190930.760197284371141=true; current-breadcrumb=; JSESSIONID=B8BF12B8A89C9AAD94884A79238ACCB6; requestedURI=../../carbon/application/load-service-provider.jsp?spName=apim_hostname; MSG16456258298740.9126911241141477=true; MSG16456258884800.25972541799729765=true; sessionNonceCookie-a1695150-f34e-4d72-a537-1caa8d8ea231=2fba0f43-2cdf-4fe5-88ea-dbfc835e24fe

]
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-25 11:43:11,583] [] DEBUG {org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor} - Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@254c4286:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@18630c7f:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/ip_of_IS:9443 remote=/5.2.192.217:60128]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-25 11:43:11,584] [] DEBUG {org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol} - Pushed Processor [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor@1fa8141e]
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-25 11:44:11,647] [] DEBUG {org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol} - Processing socket [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@18630c7f:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/ip_of_IS:9443 remote=/5.2.192.217:60128]] with status [ERROR]
TID: [-1] [] [2022-02-25 11:44:11,647] [] DEBUG {org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol} - Found processor [null] for socket [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel@18630c7f:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/ip_of_IS:9443 remote=/5.2.192.217:60128]]
```

[Login to Publisher redirects to IS, but fails to authenticate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwT7Q.png)

We have followed the WSO2 Docs but haven't figured out what we are missing.
The WSO2 Api Manager (AM) is listed as a Service Provider in WSO2 Identity Server (IS).
On the other hand, The WSO2 IS is listed as an Identity Provider in WSO2 AM.
Any help is very appreciated :) since we are struggeling with this setup for a couple of days.

Cheers,
~Bobi

Edit One: Adding screenshots with the IdP Provider and Service Provider.

[WSO2 IS side - Service Provider 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxXzc.png)

[WSO2 IS side - Service Provider 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHxgz.png)

[WSO2 IS side - Service Provider 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFYF4.png)

[WSO2 IS side - Service Provider 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1YNw.png)

Below are pics from WSO2 AM:

[WSO2 AM side - Identity Provider 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFq9I.png)

[WSO2 AM side - Identity Provider 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OASz.png)

[WSO2 AM side - Identity Provider 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vMN8.png)

Also have set Federated Authentication -->> is in Publisher's Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration, with Skip Login Consent, Skip Logout Consent and Use tenant domain in local subject identifier options checked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Signature validation has been failed while performing the SAML SSO with the Identity server from API Manager. Were you able to export the public cert of the Identity Server and add it to the IDP created in the API Manager? Please check whether the configurations related to Signature algorithms are matching and whether you have correctly uploaded the certs to the IDP created in the API Manager. Also, make sure to export the public cert of the API Manager server and add it to the SP created in the Identity Server.

Comment: @Athiththan Thanx a lot for the quick response! I have added screenshots with the setup. I will also add the config toml files. I can mention that we have exported cert files and added them from one server to another <<-- they are on separate virtual machines -->>